# How to find best range of independent variables in Random forest classification

Tags: python, classification, random-forest

I am running a binary random forest classification model and I need to know what the best possible/optimal range of each of the independent variables used in the model that drives best possible class separation. Is that possible. If not in RF can any other classifier do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can try:

- Create a df with every possible feature and predict them. You can use [pandas.MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) to create this grid and then put the result of this function into a DataFrame and them reset the index. To finish, just use this new df to predict based on your model.
- The other option is use an additive method, for example, Logistic Regression, LDA, or QDA, and analyze the coefficients.